# Strategy to migrate 10 millions mysql records into MongoDB in specific format

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, database-migration

I have 10 million MySQL records which I want to store in a way so that filters based on month and day should work well.

In Mysql, I have various tables and data are related via different joins to gather the login activity of the user, where user can be of different types/roles.

Mongo Collection should have the data in a manner so that we can easily get the data without thinking about the Mysql joins which is kind of heavy in our current scenario.

Assume I have below data set in MongoDB

```
example -  date         count  role    filter
           2020-01-01   100    admin   total
           2020-01-01   200    staff   total
           2020-01-01   35     admin   unique
```

Comment: Try adding something you tried.

Comment: Migrating from  a relational model directly to a document model will require seriously rethinking your schema and query patterns.

Comment: my count never be changed please suggest any idea